How to pass a pytorch DataLoader to huggingface Trainer? Is that even possble?
The usual steps to use the Trainer from huggingface requires that:

Load the data
Tokenize the data
Pass tokenized data to Trainer

MWE:
data = generate_random_data(10000)  # Generate 10,000 samples
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df)
tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets,
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets,
)

Instead if we do:
train_dataset = convert_to_tensors(tokenized_datasets)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataloader,
        eval_dataset=train_dataloader,
)

I get an error key 0, cause train_dataloader is not in dictionary format, I think?
Is there a way to pass directly a pytorch DataLoader to huggingface Trainer?
